It fetched the last second call duration instead of last call duration and in some devices its working fine
@SuppressLint("Range")
private suspend fun lastCallDetail(): String {
    val delayDuration = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) 3000L else 2000L
    delay(delayDuration)
    var callDuration = "0"
    try {
        val cur: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC limit 1;"
        )
        if (cur != null) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                callDuration = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION))
                break    
            }
            cur.close()
        }
    } catch (e : Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return callDuration
}
                    
private suspend fun lastCallIncoming(): String {
    delay(3000)
    var callDuration = "00:00:00"
    try {
        val cur = applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC"
        )
        val duration = cur!!.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            callDuration = cur.getString(duration)
            Log.d("callTracking", callDuration)
            break
        }
        cur.close()
        val timeSec = callDuration.toInt() // Json output
        callDuration = timeSec.toString() //hh:mm:ss formatted string
        Log.d("callTracking", callDuration)
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return callDuration
}
                    
                    
private fun secToTime(second: Int): String {
    var sec = second
    val hours = sec / 3600
    val minutes = sec % 3600/ 60
    sec %= 60
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, sec)
}

I also try this solution that returns the last- second call duration and not the last call but in some devices, it works fine where the devices have ToptoBottom call records.
@SuppressLint("Range")
private suspend fun lastCallDetail(): String {
    val delayDuration = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) 3000L else 2000L
    delay(delayDuration)
    var callDuration = "0"
    try {
        val callLogCursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC limit 1;"
        )
                        
        if (callLogCursor != null) {
            // Check the order of the call logs
            val isOrderTopToBottom = determineCallLogOrder(callLogCursor)
                        
            // Move accoreding to the determined order
            callLogCursor.moveToFirst()
            val durationIndex = callLogCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)
            if (durationIndex != -1) {
                if (isOrderTopToBottom) {
                    callDuration = callLogCursor.getString(durationIndex)
                } else {
                    callLogCursor.moveToLast()
                    callDuration = callLogCursor.getString(durationIndex)
                }
            }
            callLogCursor.close()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return callDuration
}
                        
@SuppressLint("Range")
private suspend fun lastCallIncoming(): String {
    delay(3000)
    var callDuration = "00:00:00"
    try {
        val callLogCursor = applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
            CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC"
        )
                        
        if (callLogCursor != null) {
            // Check the order of the call logs
            val isOrderTopToBottom = determineCallLogOrder(callLogCursor)
            callLogCursor.moveToFirst()
            val durationIndex = callLogCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)
                        
            // Move according to the determined order
            if (durationIndex != -1) {
                if (isOrderTopToBottom) {
                    callDuration = callLogCursor.getString(durationIndex)
                } else {
                    callLogCursor.moveToLast()
                    callDuration = callLogCursor.getString(durationIndex)
                }
                        
                val timeSec = callDuration.toInt()
                callDuration = secToTime(timeSec)
                Log.d("callTracking", callDuration)
            }
            callLogCursor.close()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return callDuration
}
    
private fun determineCallLogOrder(cursor: Cursor): Boolean {
    var isOrderTopToBottom = true
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        val dateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE)
        if (dateColumnIndex != -1) {
            val firstTimestamp = cursor.getLong(dateColumnIndex)
            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val secondTimestamp = cursor.getLong(dateColumnIndex)
                isOrderTopToBottom = firstTimestamp > secondTimestamp
            }
        }
    }
    return isOrderTopToBottom
}

check this situation - suppose I call client 1 and the duration is 50 seconds and it fetched correctly now I call client 2 its duration is 2 minutes which also fetched successfully now when I again call client 1 he doesn't pick up the call duration is fetched here wrong 50 seconds which is the last second call duration and not the last call which is 0.
it works in new devices that have the(top to bottom) call history but it creates issues on those devices have bottom-to-top call history
The query fetches call logs in descending order (CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC"),
according to the latest entries at the top iterate through the call log entries to find the one with the latest timestamp
but still, it fetched the second last call duration in some devices and in some devices its working fine, please help.

Why don't you have LIMIT 1 in query in lastCallIncoming?  As is, using DESC (without LIMIT), the following loop will exit with oldest value in callDuration.  This would be similar to what is done in lastCallDetail.

sir, i also use LIMIT 1 but still facing the same issue it's working on some devices which have top-to-bottom call history but some old devices have call history bottom to top is why it takes second last call duration in some device,
I also try timeStamps of 2 calls so i can easily determine the device call history(top to bottom) or (bottom top top)
